# A program that prints a pdf containing grey text so that all greys (or colours) go to black

Tags: pdf, printing

Often when you download .pdfs of books from Archive.org, you find that the printed text has been rendered grey. I am seeking a program runnable on 64-bit Windows 7 Pro that can print such a .pdf with all greys (and colours) going to black. Note that this is not the same as greyscale printing, which renders light colours such as yellow as grey. What I need is basically to increase the contrast by a lot.

As far as I know, this cannot be done either with PDF Xchange Viewer (version 2 build 54) or Adobe Acrobat Pro (2018.11.20058).

When I say "print", I mean that "all colours go to black" is the outcome I ultimately require in the printed hardcopy. So printing to an electronic file using PDF Creator or Adobe PDF would be fine, since I could then print in the usual way from that file. So would altering the .pdf so that it saves as the high-contrast version required. In fact either of these methods would be preferable to a route that prints in high contrast out of the printer but does not leave me with a high-contrast electronic file. But so long as I can get the high-contrast file out of the printer I will be happy.

Comment: Fax machines were typically bitonal, maybe there's a way to go through a fax emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At long last I have found a way to do this which doesn't require attending to each page individually. Here is what to do:

- print to Adobe PDF (the printer), having
- unchecked "Print in greyscale (black and white)" and
- chosen "Printer Colour Management" under Advanced | Colour Management | Colour Handling"

This creates a .pdf file that you can then send to a hardcopy printer in the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

First, try changing *Gamma* and *Contrast* in the printer *Properties* dialog. However, if you've already tried that and it's not sufficient, a graphics utility such as [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) can provide full control of the image. To use IrfanView with PDF files, [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) also must be installed. Both applications are free for personal use. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> in IrfanView to adjust contrast, brightness, gamma, etc. The image below shows the original PDF and as modified in IrfanView.

[image: PDF modified in IrfanView]

*Caveat:* Printing from IrfanView needs to be done one page at a time, AFAIK. This is not entirely a bad thing, though, since extreme changes to one page might not work well for another.

Comment: Many thanks for this. It works as you say, but unfortunately having to deal with each page individually in a long document can be unfeasible. Eventually I found a solution without using Irfan that can process a whole document.